# Write loop using ForEach intead of pipe and %

Tags: powershell, foreach, azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-service-principal

I have the following code which I am using to pull information about my `AzADServicePrincipals`.  Now, I found a code that did that using pipe like this:

```
$APPs = Get-AzADApplication
    $SPs = Get-AzADServicePrincipal
    
    $appCreds = @()
    $appCreds += $APPs | Sort-Object -Property DisplayName | % {
        $app = $_
        $sp = $SPs | ? ApplicationId -eq $cred.ApplicationId
        New-MyQLogEntry -Severity DEBUG -Message "'Fetching information for application {0}' -f $app.DisplayName"
        $app | Get-AzADAppCredential -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object -Property @{Name='DisplayName'; Expression={$app.DisplayName}}, @{Name='ObjectId'; Expression={$app.Id}}, @{Name='ApplicationId'; Expression={$app.ApplicationId}}, @{Name='UsedIn'; Expression={$app.ReplyUrls}}, @{Name='KeyId'; Expression={$_.KeyId}}, @{Name='Type'; Expression={$_.Type}}, @{Name='StartDate'; Expression={$_.StartDate -as [datetime]}}, @{Name='EndDate'; Expression={$_.EndDate -as [datetime]}}
    }
```

Adapted from: https://github.com/slapointe/azure-scripts/blob/master/azure-ad/expiring-app-credentials/Get-AzADAppExpiringCredentials.ps1

I am trying to convert this into a foreach loop instead and I am not able to.

**Background about the code:**
Get-AzADApplication will give you all your applications in your Azure account, and I am trying to find all applications of type: Service Principal (matching based on application Id) and then merging all the attributes into one Object (here $appCreds in this instance)

Answer (score 2):

- I'm assuming `$cred.ApplicationId` is a typo, since original code is using:

```
$application = $_
$application.ApplicationId
```

- The line below has no reason to be there, the variable `$sp` is not being used anywhere else (not here nor on the original code), but in case it would be in use, I would definitely change it for a `hashtable`

```
$sp = $SPs | ? ApplicationId -eq $cred.ApplicationId`
```

Below is how, in my opinion, a more classic and for sure more efficient code would look like:

```
$APPs = Get-AzADApplication
$SPs = Get-AzADServicePrincipal

$appCreds = foreach($app in $APPs | Sort-Object DisplayName)
{
    New-MyQLogEntry -Severity DEBUG -Message ('Fetching information for application {0}' -f $app.DisplayName)
    if($azAppCreds = Get-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    {
        foreach($cred in $azAppCreds)
        {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                DisplayName = $app.DisplayName
                ObjectId = $app.Id
                ApplicationId = $app.ApplicationId
                UsedIn = $app.ReplyUrls
                KeyId = $cred.KeyId
                Type = $cred.Type
                StartDate = $cred.StartDate -as [datetime]
                EndDate = $cred.EndDate -as [datetime]
            }
        }
    }   
}
```